Websocket Protocol Error (Opcode 7) when trying to connect to local Rust Game Server
I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to a Rust game server running on an Apache web server. Here's some context:

I'm running a standard configuration of Apache with the game server
using Rust under cargo run(installed using homebrew).
I'm using the latest version of macOs arm.
The same code works for my friend who's running on ubuntu.
The issue persists on both the basic brew http-server (without any
config) and Apache.
The issue persists across Safari and Chrome.
I'm connecting directly to the port Cargo is listening to (0.0.0.0:8080), and all client-side data loads correctly.

When I attempt to access the server-side code, it throws back the error message:
[ERROR ffa] [0 0] Ws error: WebSocket protocol error: Encountered invalid opcode: 7. Stopping  

Here are some steps I've already taken:

Checked firewall settings to ensure the port is open.
Verified that the game server is running and listening on the correct port.
Checked extension headings for possible misconfiguration

I'm willing to provide any relevant files or additional information upon request.

What websocket library do you use?

"The issue persists on both the basic brew http-server (without any config) and Apache" - try to connect to a websocket server without apache

@kmdreko Is the http-server still an offshoot of apache? I thought they were unique.

@trueequalsfalse tokio-tungstenite in the server code

I think I may have misunderstood, but my intention was to suggest connecting directly to the rust server without a proxy in between.

How would I do that? Don't I need a server like Apache to handle the webSocket requests? @kmdreko
